# Can I download a universal package in an external ADO feed from a specific view?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, serviceconnection

my company recently underwent an Azure DevOps migration to a new ADO organization, and I still need to download a universal package from the previous organization in the new one. I know that [this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/universal-packages-v0?view=azure-pipelines) will allow this, but I require an additional filter that the task doesn't seem to support.

I need to be able to download the universal package filtering by view. We were using [this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-package-v1?view=azure-pipelines); it supports specifying the view, but doesn't have input for external feed credentials. Does anyone know if supporting both of these demands is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I download a universal package in an external ADO feed from a specific view?

Yes. We can do it in the task: [UniversalPackages@0 - Universal packages v0 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/universal-packages-v0?view=azure-pipelines)

We can set the view at the feed field. For example: `ProjectName/feedname@Prerelease`

Yaml Sample:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
    feedsToUse: external
    externalFeedCredentials: testuniversal
    feedDownloadExternal: '123/kevintest@Prerelease'
    packageDownloadExternal: kevin
    versionDownloadExternal: '2.9.*'
```

Result:

Package view:

[image]

Pipeline result:

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thank you! I will try this out asap

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to share the result with us or if you have any questions you can also share with me.

Comment: @LoganCodes Is there any update about the ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry about that; I got busy at work and just got around to testing it. It worked like a charm, thank you!